# Difference between minimize(method=’BFGS’) and scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs

Tags: scipy

What is the main difference between `minimize(method=’BFGS’)` and `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs`? In which situations should one be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same function.

Choose the interface you prefer, `minimize` usually being easier to use also allowing to swap out the algorithm if needed.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! (Was there an easy way for me to see this?)

Comment: Easy? No. But following the sources (e.g. on github) helps here. [incomplete part of this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3c4b980d1f347f2fcbf836c7bf61d546a764cb5c/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L1077). Another hint might be the wording in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html): "See also..."